# Beautifulsoup xml no data when write()

Tags: beautifulsoup, export-to-xml

I'm connecting to an API to download some websites in xml format. I utilizing BeautifulSoup in the Jupyter environment. I'm utilizing this code to access the data...

```
my_params = {some parameters}
response = requests.get(base_url, params = my_params)
response = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'xml')
soup
```

With this code I can pull the websites in xml format just fine. Here is an example of the xml...

```
<result>
    <title>Sepsis Alliance</title>
    <contentType>html</contentType>
    <sum>...  and Sepsis Alliance has introduced new and exciting ways for individuals, medical  ... industry partners and other organizations to help shine the spotlight on sepsis. ... Spike Out Sepsis. Columbus, OH. July 23, 2016. 3rd Annual Jeffrey Ray Davis Sepsis  ... Sepsis Alliance News. June 4, 2016. Sepsis Alliance Mourns Loss of Boxing Legend Muhammad ...</sum>
    <url>www.sepsisalliance.org</url>...
```

I'm pulling 10 results in each `requests.get`. I have the need to save this xml request into an .xml file in my hard drive to further work in RStudio. I'm utilizing the following code to save the file...

```
soup = str(soup)    
file_out = open('text_mining.xml', 'a')
file_out.write(soup)
file_out.close()
```

The problem that I'm having is that the tags inside the exported .xml file are empty like so...

```
<result>
<title></title>
<contenttype></contenttype>
<sum></sum>
<url></url>
<hopcount>0</hopcount>
<size></size>
```

What are some of the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I found my bug. I had to change the `a` flag for `w` in this line of code...

```
file_out = open('text_mining.xml', 'a') # before
file_out = open('text_mining.xml', 'w') # after
```